# Prove that $f(x)e^{-inx}$ is integrable if $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

[image]

My attempt:
$$\left|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}\right|dx\leq  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|f(x)e^{-inx}\right| dx= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)||e^{-inx}|dx= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|dx\leq\infty. $$

It is my attampt is the sense that I can write it. But I dont understand several things.

Question 1: We know that $f$ is integrable by Riemann. Then $|f|$ is also integrable by Riemann in any case?

Question 2: In the above question if we replace "by Riemann" by "by Lebesgue" the answer will be the same?

Question 3: We was asked to prove that $f(x)e^{-inx}$ is integrable  by Riemann. Why we use absolute value? For me it looks like we do this just because we want to use a well-known inequlity $|\int f |\leq \int |f|$ for the sake of the proof.

Question 4: Okey. Now we know that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)e^{-inx}|dx \leq \infty$. In other words  $ |f(x)e^{-inx}|$ is integrable. Can we conclude that  $f(x)e^{-inx}$ is also integrable by Riemann in any case?

Comment: We know that a function $g$ is Riemann integrable $\iff g$ is continuous almost everywhere. In this case $f$ is Riemann integrable and hence it is continuous almost everywhere and the map $h : x \mapsto e^{-inx}$ is continuous everywhere. Therefore the product $fh$ is continuous almost everywhere and hence it is Riemann integrable.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch $$ f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & x\in \mathbb{Q},\\
-1 & x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q},
\end{cases}
  $$ is not integrable, but its absolute value is integrable. So your first statement is false or it is my misunderstanding?

Comment: @Mokhmad-SalekhKhekhaev You are right, I was careless with the Riemann integral. Here is the updated comment: Notes: 1. if $|f|$ is integrable (in the Riemann or Lebesgue sense), then automatically $f$ is also integrable in the Lebesgue sense. 2. However, the converse is not true for Riemann integrals. (Consider $\sin(x)/x$, which is Riemann integrable over $[0,∞[$ but not absolutely integrable.)

Comment: More generally: if $f,g$ are both Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, then so is $fg$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes to Riemann and Lebesgue integrals, though for different reasons: Your reasoning works for the Lebesgue integral since (with a measurability assumption as background) integrability is all about controlling the size of the function. On the other hand, for the Riemann integral you also have to worry about irregularities: For instance the function
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & x\in \mathbb{Q},\\
-1 & x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q},
\end{cases}
$$
is not Riemann integrable, but $|f|$ is. So it's not all about the size for the Riemann integral.

Nonetheless you have nice properties of the Riemann integral such as: If $f,g$ are Riemann integrable, then so is $f\cdot g$. One way to see this is to write $2f\cdot g= (f+g)^2-f^2-g^2$, and then prove the result for $f=g$. Once we have this the result you want is immediate since $g(x)=e^{-inx}$ is continuous (in particular integrable).

So to answer your questions:

1. Yes, this is true. This follows from the definition of integral as the limit of upper and lower sums and the triangle inequality.
2. Yes, and as I mentioned above, your proof goes through in that case.
3. Again see my first paragraph.
4. No, see above for a counterexample.

Comment: I’m unclear how your expression for $f\cdot g$ helps, when $f$ integrable does not imply $f^2$ integrable

Comment: @FShrike: Not for the Lebesgue integral, but it's true for the Riemann one (recall that R-integrable functions are bounded).

Comment: @Jose27 You have answered "Yes" for my first question (if $f$ is Riemann integrable then $|f|$ is also). But $sin( x)/x$ is integrable, but its absolute value is not. How to understand it?

Comment: I also don’t understand the $f$ times $g$ part: $\frac1{\sqrt x}$ is Riemann integrable over $[0,1]$, but it’s square not.

Comment: Actually wait: I think there is a further source of confusion caused by me: Maybe $1/x$ is considered Riemann integrable (but with integral $\infty$) ? In that case my terminology is not the same as that of the OP @Mokhmad which may cause confusion.

Comment: @Mokhmad-SalekhKhekhaev: That function is not Riemann integrable in the usual sense the term is used: Riemann integrable functions are necessarily bounded. You can define the *improper* integral of it, but that's not the same thing. That function is not Lebesgue integrable either (which is, in my opinion, another reason to keep the improper integrals separated).

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: Please see my above comment; Riemann integrable functions (in the sense the term is usually used) are necessarily bounded. Your function is *improper* Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Jose27 That makes sense and I agree with you now!

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1: As explained with the standard example in the comments, it is not true in any case. But here it holds since $f$ Riemann integrable implies $|f|$ Riemann integrable on a compact set (seen as composition of riemann integrable function with a continuous function).

Answer 2: Since we are on a closed and bounded interval, Riemann integrablilty implies Lebesgue integrability, so all works there too.

Answer 3: By answer 2, you can just work with Lebesgue integral and showing that the integral of your function $g$ is finite. Hence, using your majorization you get the result.

Answer 4: Nope, the converse of answer 2 does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere along the way you learned that the product of two Riemann integrable (RI) functions is RI. Here we have $f$ which is RI, and $e^{in\theta},$ which is continuous and hence RI. Therefore $f(\theta)\cdot e^{in\theta}$  is RI.